# Create partition in Tree View

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Can we make a partition(one besides another) in Tree view?
I don't know whether it is possible, because whenever I tried, I wasn't allowed to do so!
Maybe you can get a clear idea about what I'm asking through the Screenshot on the below link!
I want to make a "Paying Guest" Tree view besides the "Choose Hostels".
[image]

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please describe in detail ? because your screenshot describe nothing.

Comment: I want to make partition in Tree View just like we do in Form view (using <group>). So, is there any particular tag or method so that I can do the same in Tree View?

Comment: No you can not divide like `<group>` in form view.You can use `group by` instead.